# How to update min_index_interval and max_index_interval of a table in a running Cassandra Cluster

Tags: cassandra, datastax

How to update `min_index_interval` and `max_index_interval` of a table in a
running Cassandra cluster?

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TABLE keyspace.table
with min_index_interval = 512 
AND max_index_interval = 2048;
```

You can use above query to change the property.